# How to cancel scheduler job when alarm fire off

Tags: java, android, multithreading, job-scheduling, jobservice

I have 2 alarms in one alarm I'm starting job scheduler service that sends notifications every 30 minutes and at the second alarm I want to cancel this scheduled job service, also I'm sending notification on main thread I didn't make separate thread in job service, here is my code:

This is my jobinfo object and I'm executing this method when broadcast of start alarm fires off

```
public static void Scheduler(Context context){

     float duration = NotificationUtills.NotificationCounter();

     ComponentName componentName = 
     new ComponentName(context , ClsJobService.class);

    JobInfo.Builder builder =  new JobInfo.Builder(0, componentName)
            .setPeriodic(5000);


    JobScheduler jobScheduler = 
    (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService (Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}
```

And this is job service

```
public class ClsJobService extends JobService {

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

    //logic for building and sending notification
    NotificationUtills.notificationBuilder(getApplicationContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Is it alright not to create separate thread?

Also how can i cancel this scheduled job when second alarm fires off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it alright not to create separate thread?

It is, as long as your `Notification` building logic does not do anything time consuming that might hurt the responsiveness of the app.

> Also how can i cancel this scheduled job when second alarm fires off?

You can call the [`cancel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#cancel(int)) method of `JobScheduler`.
It takes the job ID as a parameter. This has to be the same job ID you passed to the `JobInfo.Builder` constructor (`0` in your code).

Comment: Is JobService can only be used with job scheduler?

Comment: @blackHawk Well, `JobService` is basically a `Service`, so you could use it as a simple `Service` (starting it with `Context.startService()` etc.), but it wouldn't make much sense to do so. It is intended to use with the `JobScheduler`.